# How do I get SEO friendly URLs with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Trying to build my own social media for a project.
I have a php script on profile.php which queries the user database for either an "id" or a custom "/my.user" url.
When I enter it in the url, which I want it to be like: mysite.com/my.user it works with this code:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ ./profile.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But the htaccess doesn't let me to put in the "id" of the profile, so mysite.com/20 for example doesn't work.
I have tried another htaccess code, but that works the same as the above:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&_@\.]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So to clear things up;

- This works: mysite.com/my.user
- This does not: mysite.com/20 or mysite.com/myuser

I expect to get this working:

- mysite.com/20
- mysite.com/my.user

What should I do?

Full .htaccess code:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^./profile.php


RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ ./profile.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

What happens right now is that mysite.com/my.user (special user url) is working, but not if a user has no dots, like mysite.com/myuser. Then it tries to get myuser.php which doesn't exists.
Also when I enter the "id" from "my.user" like: mysite.com/20 it just says "profile not found", so something happens there.

This is the profile.php query code:

```
$profile = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_GET['u']);
if (filter_var($profile, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) == true) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM UserProfile, Location WHERE UserProfile.id = '$profile' AND Location.id = '$profile'";
} else {
    $queryurl = "SELECT id FROM UserProfile WHERE UserProfile.ProfileUrl = '$profile'";
    if ($result2 = $mysqli->query($queryurl)) {
        while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            $userid = $row2['id'];
        }
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM UserProfile, Location WHERE UserProfile.ProfileUrl = '$profile' AND Location.id = '$userid'";
    $result2->free();
}
```

---

Best regards, Erik.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What does it do, what do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: I think he means that he wants profile.php?u=20 (where 20 is the ID) to be available aswell as the custom url (my.user) in his example

Comment: @deceze I updated the post, and yes, as Dennis said.

Comment: But **what** is happening *right now*? Redirect loop? Internal 500 server error? 404 Page not found?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ What happens right now is that mysite.com/my.user (special user url) is working, but not if a user has no dots, like mysite.com/myuser. Then it tries to get myuser.php which doesn't exists. Also when I enter the "id" from "my.user" like: mysite.com/20 it just says "profile not found", so something happens there.

I added the query code in the post.

Comment: https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/

Comment: I used to make use of mod_rewrite myself but it gets pretty tedious when you switch machines. Most light weight frameworks offer SEO friendly routing or you could roll out your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that your first rule matches any non existent uri and rewrites it to /uri.php so your 2nd is never triggered.

Change

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

To

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

so the rule can match existent php files only.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I'm not that good with htaccess, it took my 15 hours, I love you! :-)